# Not showing any networks in wifi suddenly

Tags: networking, wireless

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 till yesterday evening it was working perfectly fine but suddenly after I restarted the laptop as it was lagging alot it stopped showing any wifi connection. I've tried resetting settings to default by terminal but there is no change. It's showing **connection activation failed.** But working ok if connected to my phone thru ethernet. And it is lagging alot as well.

Comment: Try to run an older kernel in Grub menu